# Create M3U playlists for iBasso DX50 on Linux

Tags: linux, playlists, music-management

I'm using an iBasso DX50 as my music player and I use Linux as my primary OS. I need to create M3U playlists to be imported into my iBasso DX50. I would try and edit some of the files myself but I don't know what the root to SD-Card path looks like from inside my iBasso. Any ideas?

Comment: Removed software rec portion of question which is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Example for create M3U playlist:

All files type *.mp3, *.wav and *.wma

```
$ find . \( -name \*.mp3 -o -name \*.wav -o -name \*.wma \) \ > playlist.m3u
```

All files type *.WAV, *.Mp3, etc (not case sensitive)

```
$ find . -iregex '.*\.\(mp3\|wav\|wma\)' > playlist.m3u
```

Without recursive search in directory

```
printf %s\\n *.mp3 > playlist.m3u
```

And, finally:

> **How to use the import/export playlist function?** After the playlist is built in the DX50, press the thumbnail icon in front of the
>   playlist to unfold the options. Press "export playlist", then one can
>   find a M3U playlist under the M3U folder under the internal flash.
>
> **To import a M3U playlist**, load the M3U playlist into the internal flash or a Micro SD card. Then find the M3U playlist under Directory.
>   Press the M3U playlist to start importing the playlist.

From DX50 user guide: http://www.ibasso.com/uploadfiles/20141203/201412031740555098.pdf